# OpenCV convolution/filter2d with complex kernel

Tags: opencv, convolution

Is there a function in OpenCV which takes a complex matrix as a kernel to convolve/filter an image?

Comment: @William That is correlation. I want convolution.

Comment: You're right. filter2D() is what you need. But dont forget that convolution and correlation are a flip away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function [filter2D()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) meets your requirement. Pay attention to the `int ddepth` paratmer, when you apply floating-point kernels on `uchar` image.

Comment: How do I input complex numbers in a kernel matrix? I thought you need a double channel matrix for that and filter2D takes only a single channel kernel.

Comment: @BananaCode well, sorry for missing "complex". Well, as far as I know, OpenCV image filtering can not use more than one channel filter kernel. If your kernel is complex, then your data may be stored as a 2-channel vector/matrix. Maybe, you need to use `split()` to process each channel independently. Besides, why do you need to do convolution in frequency domain ?

Comment: yeah that is what I ended up doing. I split the kernel into the real and imaginary part and filtered the image separately with both.
I need it because I was copying a MATLAB script into C++, which uses a Kernel with complex numbers.

Comment: @rookiepig, you can convolve real matrix with complex kernel to find gradient vector which has nothing to do with "frequency domain"